# How to echo variable containing html in php

Tags: php, html

I have a variable which contains a html iframe which i get from a third-party package. When I do

```
<?php echo $variable ?>
```

my page displays the raw html, with the html tags but I want it to be interpreted as html and displayed correctly. Someone enlighten me on how to do this, or what I'm missing?

Comment: The browser will render as html, unless you actually don't have an html or have some header telling the browser that it's not html but something else. What's the content of `var_dump($variable);`

Comment: Check this function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Thanks @Felippe Duarte, this woks as expected. Please add it as an answer

Comment: If that works, the variable doesn't actually contain HTML. It contains HTML with all the special characters encoded.

Comment: You are right @Barmar, a `var_dump` of the variable verifies it's in fact encoded.

Comment: There you go @The7thMonarch

Comment: be careful, decode also your other variables which should NOT contain HTML. So you can prevent XSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you don't have a HTML code encoded with [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Use `html_entity_decode($variable);` to decode your string and display in browser.